# Passing an object into a factory

Tags: java, spring, factory-pattern

I have a singleton class that manages all my services. I am replacing this singleton with a factory pattern. All of the services have an `initialize()` and a `close()`. Most my services take in constructor arguments and vary from service to service - this is where the design starts to fall apart.

I am using Spring Boot to initialize my `singletonCache`. There are some services that Spring does not manage because they need to be created at runtime.

In my factory class, I created a method that allows passing of existing objects via an argument. I store these instances in `instanceCache` and retrieve them later on. The `registerInstanceService(string, class, object)` allows me to register existing objects with varying constructor arguments. I am not sure if this would be considered anti-pattern.

Here is a summary of the factory:

```
@Service
public class ServiceFactory {

    @Autowired
    private List<PlatformService> services;

    private static final Map<Class<? extends PlatformService>, PlatformService> singletonCache = new HashMap<>();

    private static final Map<String, PlatformService> instanceCache = new HashMap<>();

    @PostConstruct
    public void initializeSingletonCache() {
        services.forEach(service -> {
            singletonCache.put(service.getClass(), service);
            service.initialize();
        });
    }

    public static <T extends PlatformService> T registerInstanceService(String serviceName, Class<T> service) throws RuntimeException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        if (instanceCache.containsKey(serviceName)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("An instance with the name " + serviceName + " has already been created");
        }

        T serviceObject = service.newInstance();
        instanceCache.put(serviceName, serviceObject);
        serviceObject.initialize();
        return serviceObject;

    }

    public static <T extends PlatformService> void registerInstanceService(String serviceName, T service) throws Exception {
        if (instanceCache.containsKey(serviceName)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("An instance with the name " + serviceName + " has already been created");
        }

        service.initialize();
        instanceCache.put(serviceName, service);
    }

    public static <T extends PlatformService> T getService(Class<T> service) {
        return service.cast(singletonCache.get(service));
    }

    //...
    //getters

}
```

So I guess my question is, is this an appropriate way to handle my use case? Have I violated my agreement with the pattern?

Comment: why do you need at all this `registerInstanceService(String serviceName, Class<T> service)` - what is the reason to put the responsibility of creating services on your handler?

Comment: It is a shorthand to invoking objects that take no arguments in their constructor. But you are correct, it is just boiler plate.

Comment: so delete this bolier plate and you will have consistent way to keep your objects in the factory ;) I would also suggest to not create two `HashMap`s but one (if it is not possible to use only one of String/Class key create something like `Tuple<Class, String>` as a key), and provide some `abstract T getThis()` method in services to avoid unchecked casting in the runtime

Answer (score 0):

What you are implementing is a Simple Factory.

> In my factory class, I created a method that allows passing of existing objects via an argument.

This doesn´t really seems like Factory, if you are **passing** this objects to this factory class it means they were created somewhere else... so this factory didn´t acomplished it purpose.

> The registerInstanceService(string, class, object) allows me to register existing objects with varying constructor arguments.

I didn´t saw this method signature anywhere in your code.

Comment: I am representing `T` generic as `object` to show intent. See `registerInstanceService(String serviceName, T service)`